# to mark a time/date/season

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

can you "mark" a season or date or time ahead for doing something in the future.

For instance, can I say "***The season he had marked for his arrival has come***
Is this sentence correct?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. You can *mark* a date/time/month/day on the calendar.

Comment: Yes, but I would not say that unless you are using direct speech in a historical story: it sounds about 300 years out of date.

Comment: @Greybeard Yes, this is a historical story. The character had promised to come back after his voyage in a particular season.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this sentence is correct. **Mark** in this case means "to designate as if by a mark" (Merriam-Webster). You can be marked for promotion at your job, for instance. This figurative use of mark is somewhat rare, but not unheard of. The use of mark to mean physically marking something is much more common. I do not know the context of this passage, so I am not sure if the character had physically marked a calendar or something, but even if he hadn't, this would still be correct.

[https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mark]
Entry 2, Def. 2a(1)

Comment: A historical story and the "marking" referred here is an agreed upon time for the character's return after a long journey. It is more of a promise to come back in a particular season of the year.

Answer (score 3):

We would be more likely to refer to a time or date we had *chosen*, *picked*, *pencilled in* (informal, with the sense of provisional designation) or *designated* (formal and precise).

Comment: had chosen sounds good

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. For example you can say:

> I'm going to go to the store next Thursday.
>
> Next April is when I'm expecting my newborn baby.
>
> I'm going to go to his birthday party on 5/10/2020.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to communicate, I would instead say something like:

> It was (whatever season you want here), soon he would arrive at his destination.

or instead

> The season he had been waiting for had finally come. Soon he would arrive at his destination.

Comment: Andy, the question is about the use of the verb **mark** in this sense. You might want to reconsider your answer.